# AWS RDS last connection date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have searched for an answer on google, here, aws forums, etc. I have also extensively browsed the boto3 docs. I am trying to fnd info on listing RDS instances and the last time any connection was made to them using boto3.

I can fnd no information on this whatsoever. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This information is stored inside of the database server and each type (i.e. PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) does it differently.  You will need to find out where that information is stored for each type and run a query to get that information.

Comment: Which database engine are you using? What type of "connection" do you mean? boto3 is used to _manage_ the database (eg stop, start, add storage), but connections _to_ the database for querying are typically done outside of boto3 (eg via JDBC connection). Please Edit your question to provide extra details.

Comment: I actually only need metadata about the db; analogous to the info you might get regarding an ec2 instance (when it was created, the ami, whether or not it is stopped/started, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I found this information available in Trusted Advisor --> Cost optimization